# how to change the check box state is true when treeview SelectedNodeChanged event in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

In my asp.net web application, i have a tree view control with checkbox enabled.Now i want to change the check box state to True when `SelectedNodeChanged` event fired.

```
 protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            //code
 }
```

Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SelectedNode has a `Checked` property which points to the checkbox of the item. You can set it checked by setting the `Checked` property to **true**.

```
 TreeView1.SelectedNode.Checked = true;
```

To check all the child-nodes you can do the following:

```
 foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes)
    node.Checked = true;
```

Comment: @Thanks Brain: And also i want to check If it is Parent Node then make the all check box true of the Childnodes.Is it possible?

Comment: Yup, that can be done. See the edit I've made to know how to do so :)